# AttrubuteError: 'Game' object has no attrubute 'green' вот расположение и причина ошибки File "Game3", line 163, in (module) snake = Snake(game.green)

Tags: python, pygame

```
import pygame
import sys
import random
import time

class Game():
    def __unit__(self):
        # Размеры
        self.screen_width = (720)
        self.screen_height = (460)

        # Цвета

        self.red = pygame.Color(255, 0, 0)
        self.green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
        self.white = pygame.Color(255, 255, 255)
        self.dark = pygame.Color(0, 0, 0)         
        self.brown = pygame.Color(165, 42, 42)

        # Счетчик FPS
        self.fps_controller = pygame.time.clock()

    def init__and_check_for_errors():

        check_errors = pygame.init()

        if check_errors[1] > 0:
            sys.exit()

        else:
            print("Ок, да...")

    def set_surface_and_title(self):
        self.play.surface = pygame.display.setmode((
            self.screen_height, screen_height))
        pygame.display.set_caption("Моя сестра")

    def evet_loop():
            #Добавляем ивент
        for event in pygame.get():
            #Нажатие на клавиши клавы
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT or event.key == ord("d"):
                    change_to = "RIGHT"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT or event.key == ord("a"):
                    change_to = "LEFT"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_UP or event.key == ord("w"):
                    change_to = "UP"
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN or event.key == ord("s"):
                    change_to = "DOWN"

                #Выход из игры(ESP)

                elif event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    pygame.quit()
                    sys.exit()
        return change_to

    def refresh_screen(self):
        pygame.display.flip()
        game.fps_controller.tick(23)

    def show_score(self, choice=1):
        #Отображение Очков...
        s_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 24)
        s_surf = s_font.render(
            'Очки: {0}'.format(self.score), True, self.red)

        if choice == 1:
            s_rect.midtop(80, 10)
        self.play_surface.bilt(s_surf, s_rect)

    def game_over(self):
        go_font = pygame.font.SysFont('monaco', 72)
        go_surf = go_font.render('Хах, Проебался', True, self.red)
        go_rect = go_surf.get_rect()
        go_rect.midtop(360,15)
        self.play_surface.bilt(go_surf, go_rect)
        self.show_score(0)
        pygame.display.flip()
        time.sleep(3)
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

class Snake():
    def __init__ (self, snake_color):

    #Сама змейка, а точнее голова, тело будет дальше.
        self.snake_head_pos = (100, 50)
    #Само тело + голова
        self.snake_body = [[100, 50], [90, 50], [80, 50]]
        self.snake_color = snake_color
    #Изначально направление змеи
        self.direction = "RIGHT"
    #Куда будет менятся направления змеи, при нажатии на клавиши клавы
        self.change_to = self.direction

    def validate_direction_and_change(self):
        if any((self.change_to == "RIGHT" and not self.direction == "LEFT",
                self.change_to == "LEFT" and not self.direction == "RIGHT",
                self.change_to == "UP" and not self.direction == "DOWN",
                self.change_to == "DOWN" and not self.direction == "UP")):
            self.change_to = self.direction 

    def head_snake_pos(self):
        if self.direction == "RIGHT":
            self.snake_head_pos[0]+= 10
        elif self.direction == "LEFT":
            self.snake_head_pos[0]-= 10
        elif self.direction == "UP":
            self.snake_head_pos[1]-= 10
        elif self.direction == "DOWN":
            self.snake_head_pos[1]+= 10

    def snake_body_mechanism(self):
        self.insert(0, list(self.snake_head_pos))

        if (self.snake_head_pos[0] == self.food_pos[0] and
                self.snake_head_pos[1] == self.food_pos[1]):

            food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_width/10)*10,
                        random.randrange(1, screen_height/10)*10]
            score += 1
        else:
            self.snake_body.pop()
            return score, food_pos

    def draw_snake(self, play_surface, surface_color):
        play_surface.fill(surface_color)
        for pos in self.snake_body:
            pygame.draw.rect(
                play_surface, self.snake_color, pygame.Rect(
                    pos[0], pos[1], 10, 10))

    def check_for_boundaries(self, game_over, screen_width, screen_height):
        if any((
            self.snake_head_pos[0] > screen_width -10
            or self.head_snake_pos[0] < 0,
            self.snake_head_pos[1] > screen_height -10
            or self.head_snake_pos[1] < 0
            )):
            game_over()
        for block in self.snake_body[1:]:
            if(block[0] == self.snake_head_pos[0]
                and block[1] == self.snake_head_pos[1]):
                game_over()

class Food():
    def __unit__(self, food_color, screen_height, screen_width):
        self.food_color = food_color
        self.food_size_y = 10
        self.food_size_x = 10
        self.food_pos = [random.randrange(1, screen_height/10)*10,
                        random.randrange(1, screen_width/10)*10]

    def draw_food(self, play_surface):
        pygame.draw.rect(
        play_surface, self.food_color, pygame.Rect(
            self.food_pos[0], self.food_pos[1],
            self.food_size_y, self.food_size_x))

'''game = Game()
snake = Snake(game.green)
food = Food(game.brown, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

game.init__and_check_for_errors()
game.set_surface_and_title()

while True:
    snake.change_to = game.event_loop(snake.change_to)

    snake.validate_direction_and_change()
    snake.change_head_position()
    game.score, food.food_pos = snake.snake_body_mechanism(
        game.score, food.food_pos, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)
    snake.draw_snake(game.play_surface, game.white)

    food.draw_food(game.play_surface)

    snake.check_for_boundaries(
        game.game_over, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)

    game.show_score()
    game.refresh_screen()'''
```

Comment: Не `def __unit__(self):`, а `def __init__(self):`

Comment: Нет не помогло, такая же ошибка, но место ошибки другое

Comment: Дайте угадаю? Вот это - `Food(game.brown, game.screen_width, game.screen_height)`?

Comment: нет 'self.fps_controller = pygame.time.clock()' вот это

Comment: Понятно, то есть вы хотите, чтобы мы тут все ваши косяки и незнания основ питона исправили путем сканирования вашего сознания на расстоянии? В Food тоже надо `__unit__` на `__init__` поменять

Comment: Нет, извините, что я спросил, да ведь новичку надо не спрашивать у более опытных, чтобы они указали на ошибки, ну да, ну да, в общем вы правы, спасибо за помощь больше вас не побеспокою

Comment: И да кстати я исправил то что вы сказали все равно ошибка та же

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 1):

Исправляем `__unit__` на `__init__`, смотрим в документацию и меняем `pygame.time.clock()` 
на [pygame.time.Clock](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html#pygame.time.Clock):

```py
import pygame

class Game():
    def __init__(self):
        self.green = pygame.Color(0, 255, 0)
        self.fps_controller = pygame.time.Clock

class Snake():
    def __init__(self, color):
        self.snake_color = color

game = Game()
snake = Snake(game.green)
```

[Все работает и никаких тех же ошибок.](https://onlinegdb.com/BkZY1mK3L)